# Method GET and Htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have a form method with GET type

After clicking the submit button my link is "/browse.php?category=0&search=something" and I want /browse/0/something ..

I tried to redirect by htaccess but didn't works

> ```
> Redirect ^browse.php?category=(.+)&search=(.+)$ http://127.0.1/browse/$1/$2
> ```

thank you !

Answer (score 0):

first of all it should be `127.0.0.1`

Redirect is directive from `mod_alias` module. Make sure you have enabled it.
Also, `Redirect` does not support regex matching for that you will have to use `RedirectMatch`.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^browse.php?category=(.+)&search=(.+)$ http://127.0.0.1/browse/$1/$2 [NC,L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^browse/(.+)/(.+)/?$ browse.php?category=$1&search=$2 [NC,L]
```

I hope you have enabled `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: ? `Redirect` doesn't support regexp matching.

Comment: @TerryE my bad was supposed to put in rewriterule.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to emit the URI `/browse/0/something` then this is pretty easy to code client-side with javascript.  But if you want a temporary redirect server-side then remember that you can't put query string parameters in the `RedirectRule`.  Add the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} \bcategory=(.+?)&search=(.+)$
RewriteRule   ^browse\.php$   browse/%1/%2?               [R=302]
```

Comment: You might want to change your %1 and %2 to $1 and $2 on your last line.

Comment: @sgermain06, why? Surely I want the answer to work? The $ variables match the `RewriteRule` regexp.  The % patterns match relate to the previous `RewriteCond` regexp, which is why I used them.

Comment: Nop, didn't work... Can you tell me an exemple of javascript ?

Comment: Well it works for me, but if your internal application is really browse.php then things get more complicated because you also need to do the internal redirect back again  `/browse/0/something` to `browse.php`.  "Didn't work" is a really helpful description :(